# What is the relationship between site traffic and memory usage?

Tags: node.js, memory

I have a Node application that has been running for a while.  I've been monitoring the memory use over time and I have noticed that memory usage on the servers stay about the same regardless of whether there is a small number of active users or a large number of users.

In Node, what is the relationship between the number of active users and the amount of memory it uses?  Based on what I have seen there does not appear to be any real connection.  Is this just because I am not dealing with huge numbers of active users (the highest I've seen is about 100 active users)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is great comparison of node and Apache under different load.

http://zgadzaj.com/benchmarking-nodejs-basic-performance-tests-against-apache-php

In general node should be much more efficient in memory usage because it doesn't create threads for each requests, so memory will grow but only for user data not for threads.